# Is there any Automation Framework that supports both Web and Mobile Application?

Tags: automation, framework, software-testing

Currently we are working with an Angular JS application and performing E2E with Protractor in Jamsmine framework. I just need to know about the framework that supports both this Web application and Hybrid mobile application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I declared to be heavily biased[1] but since you asked directly: [Squish GUI Tester](https://www.froglogic.com/squish/) is available in editions for Web, Android, iOS and more that can be combined for hybrid testing. Be it for plain Web UIs, native mobile Apps or cases of WebViews embedded into native applications.

The way it works is based on an abstraction of UI elements in a toolkit-neutral model that can be used for test interactions and verifications. Python, JavaScript, Perl, Tcl or Ruby are available for scripting.

When looking for tools you may want to differ between those that solely rely on Automation interfaces and those that can interact with an application natively. Image-based interactions and verifications (including OCR) can be a nice plus in case of custom controls as well.

[1] due to my co-authorship of this tool.

Comment: Thanks @Harri.. I am looking for some open source tool also